# SYSINFO.nOSMinor returning wrong version for Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1

Tags: installshield

For InstallScript projects, does anyone know why InstallShield 2012 returns 6.2 in the SYSINFO values for Windows 8.1 and Windows 2012 R2 which should be returning 6.3? Specifically in the SYSINFO.nOSMajor and SYSINFO.nOSMinor versions numbers.

If this is simply a bug in InstallShield are there any other ways to detect the OS version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the InstallShield community thread [Installscript Project - Target machine setting recognizing Windows 8.1 as Windows 8](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?214188-Installscript-Project-Target-machine-setting-recognizing-Windows-8-1-as-Windows-8-p). Note that there are two downloads referenced:

1. [Updated manifest files](http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/ISSUE/Windows-Compatibility-Issues-on-Windows-8-1-and-Server-2012-R2-for-Suite-and-InstallScript-Projects) so that Windows's compatibility shims don't interfere; this can be applied to any recent version of InstallShield.
2. A fix for a bug that the first revealed in InstallShield 2013; this doesn't affect previous versions that lack explicit support for Windows 8.1, and should only be applied to InstallShield 2013.

Comment: That's a fix for InstallShield 2013, not 2012. We don't have those constants defined at all in 2012, which is why I'm trying to use the SYSINFO.nOSMajor and SYSINFO.nOSMinor properties instead of the SYSINFO.nISOSL property.

Comment: Yes you're quite right. This post was very useful in explaining why it does it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864730/why-os-version-reports-windows-8-0-for-windows-8-1. Those manifests do work ok for IS2012 so that it puts the right version number in the SYSINFO fields now.